# chield flex-direction row not working react native?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, styles

i'm new to react native. i'm implement restaurant app. when i try flex direction row in parent is working but when i try chield it is now working

that is my design [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9T57.jpg)

but i need like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEhIj.png)

i try this code

```
 <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <View>
                        <Image style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} source={require('../../Assets/restaurant.jpg')} />
                    </View>

                    <View>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <View>
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: commonStyles.simpleTextValue, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'black' }}>RajDhani</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View>
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'gray' }}>12PM to 10PM</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    </View>
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a working example on online code editor's like expo snack

Comment: ok i try to add in expo snack @AppCity

Comment: Dont worry about it, found the issue, I will write the answer now

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the parent component width,

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <View>
                        <Image style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} source={require('../../Assets/restaurant.jpg')} />
                    </View>
     <View style={{ width:'100%'}}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center', width:'100%', backgroundColor:'red' }}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={{  fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'black', width:'100%' }}>RajDhani</Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'gray' }}>12PM to 10PM</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
</View>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but that is not my question i send picture of my problem and if i add image than it is not working

Comment: it should work if you have the same code as above with the image and parent. i will update answer with full code.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <View style={leftView}>
    <Image source={{uri: 'some image'}} style={someStyle}/>
    <Rating />
  </View>
  <View style={rightView}>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row,justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
      <Text>Raj Dhani</Text>
      <Text>12pm to 10pm</Text>
    </View>  
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row,justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
      <Text>Rajastani Lunch</Text>
      <Text>20% off on Dinner</Text>
    </View>  
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row,justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
      <Text>Rs 600/head</Text>
      <Text>Tuesday Lunch @225</Text>
    </View>  
  </View>
</View>
```

P.S:
Please add other styles on you own ;)